# kubelet certificate manager failure after certificate rotation

Tags: ssl, certificate, kubernetes

Today our lab k8s cluster stopped allowing work on the cluster. When I dug in, it was because the certificates expired.

I regenerated the certs and configs but when I restart kubelet, we still get `connection refused` to the apiserver. The apiserver is running, but port 6443 is not open. When debugging logs, the following error is in the output (maybe a red herring, but not sure):

`Current certificate CN (system:node:lab-02) does not match requested CN (system:node:control-plane-xm2c9)`

This is a `kubeadm` created cluster. I used `kubeadm` to regenerate all of the certs (except the CA). The following commands were used:

```
# kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans control-plane-xm2c9 --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.2.78
# kubeadm init phase certs apiserver-etcd-client
# kubeadm init phase certs apiserver-kubelet-client
```

I created the configs with:

```
# kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.2.78
# kubeadm init phase kubeconfig kubelet  --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.2.78
# kubeadm init phase kubeconfig controller-manager --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.2.78
# kubeadm init phase kubeconfig scheduler --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.2.78
```

I'm still sifting through logs. I think this is the root of my problem, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any assistance would be great! TIA

Comment: is `Current certificate CN (system:node:lab-02) does not match requested CN (system:node:control-plane-xm2c9)` the only you found useful in logs?

Comment: Yeah, in the k8s logs. One thing I failed to do was check the `docker` logs, which finally indicated that the `sa` keys were missing from the `pki` directory. Then I also noticed that `/var/lib/kubernetes/pki`contained the `apiserver-client-*` key pair. That one was the old set of keys trying to use the old hostname. Lastly, `etcd` was also trying to use the old hostname, so I fixed that in `/etc/kubernetes/etcd/*`. It was a PITA.

Comment: great to hear you fixed issue - ill ask you provide your own answer in case you resolved everythng you asked in this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem, if I remember correctly, was that there was on cert that the above-mentioned commands did not update but was required. It was the `sa` cert. Fortunately, before I started any work on this, I backed up all of the certs to `/var/tmp` and the `sa` cert was in there and still valid. When I copied the `sa` cert back to the cert directory and restart `kubelet` then everything worked again.